# UITextView doesn't scroll to caret after becoming first responder on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, ios7

I have `UITableViewCell` and in this cell I have `UITextView` with some text. When I call `becomeFirstResponder` on `iOS 6` then it works as expected and the table view scrolls to caret but this doesn't work on `iOS 7`.

I have also `UITextFields` in cells and it works fine with `becomeFirstResponder` on `iOS 7`. Just `UITextView` is a problem.

**Is it a bug or what did they change?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with my solution that utilizes a method `(void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated` from `UITableView` and a method `(CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position` from `UITextInput` and after doing some math with heights. I have achieved same behavior as on iOS 6. It is not so nice but it works.

If anyone will come with a better solution, let me know.